# Open rates for each list for an email sent out to multiple lists

Tags: email, list, pardot

I have sent out a list email to multiple lists, for instance Boston and Chicago. I'd like to view metrics like open rate, etc for each list. I am able to view these metrics for the email as a whole, but is there any way to get these metrics for prospects in each list, Boston and Chicago, separately?

Comment: Hi HKS. Did you send out the email to each list individually, or did you include all lists in one send?

Comment: Hi Felix. We sent out a single email with all lists included.

Comment: I'm not sure then. You could look into the open and click data views for that send ID, export it and do some Excel magic to calculate the metrics for each list, but it would be a cumbersome workaround and not realy an in-suite solution. If you find a solution for it within Marketing Cloud, I'd like to know too :)

Comment: Thanks, will let you know if I figure it out.